# Automated testing - Best practice - getting test data before test

Tags: testing, automated-tests, bdd, ui-automation, specflow

I have a question about getting test data for automated testing, here is my problem:
I need to prepare automated testing scripts for a clothes shop.
And I need to know what is the **best practice** for getting test data needed for the following scenario:

Scenario description: Checking if a user can correctly add a product to the basket.

Given I am on the "WOMEN'S DRESSES" page

When  I add "XXX" product to the bag

Then  I can see "XXX" product displayed in the basket

My question is: how to ensure that the "XXX" product is always available and what is the best practice for this?
Do I have to always connect to the env database and check if the "XXX" product is available and if not then insert it into DB?

Or maybe should modify a little BDD scenario and get the list of currently available products on the "WOMEN'S DRESSES" page, chose any product, add it to the bag and check if it is correctly added to the basket? ( but in that case what to do if there are no products available for the testing env ?)

I want to have efficient and strong automated tests.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for this. Some developers and I looked into a similar problem we had for a car-marketplace. We actually found out that the "dirty" way was the best way for us.

We simply did a BeforeFeature database query and picked up all brands which were available in the test environment. We added these brands to FeatureContext and ScenarioContext, depending on the required context. Because of the Feature/Scenario context, you can use these values during the run of that particular feature/scenario. During the "When" step, in the code, we created a list of all the brands available in the database.

Then, we passed every brand through specflow to the code and checked the list if it contained the brand. If the list did contain the brand, a click had to take place on that brand and we checked in the last step if we were landed on the page of that brand.

You could do something similar with the dresses.

So our specflow looked somewhat like:

```
Scenario Outline: Check available brands till vehicle detail page
Given I navigate to Vehichle Search Page

When I search '<Brand>', if available in test environment 

Then I am navigated to the vehicle detail page

Examples:
|Brand|
|Audi |
|BMW  |
|etc  |
```

Just an addition:
This way of writing test keeps your test very BDD. Business can read what your are testing. Also, as long as the data model remains as-is, your tests are very maintainable. You can add unlimited amounts of dresses to your table and you will only get test results if the brands are available. So if the database is swiped clean, sure, not a single test will be executed, but you won't get any false positives or unnecessary negatives.

Also, you can choose to add brands to the database if they weren't found in the first place. You could do this within the "When" step. If the dress is not found in the list, you can add it with a query in the database at that moment.

Comment: Cheers, that helps!
 I am going to try your approach

Comment: If you have any more questions, let me know

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to add one more precondition:

**GIVEN: XXX product is available on the "WOMEN'S DRESSES" page.**

*If product is not available - it's another test case )*

Create XXX product just before test using most suitable way:

- api call
- web UI
- DB update (not recommended)

or just mock api response for XXX product

Comment: Thank you, every answer is precious, could you explain to me why DB update is not recommended?

Comment: Because usually application does some verification and then update DB. This update is also can be complex query.
If you are using direct DB update (as app does) you should be fully sure that it's correct and up to date.

Comment: This is good. Another alternative is to write the step as @ModX suggested, then in the step check to see if the dress is present, and add it (any way you choose, with the risks ModX correctly outlines) if it isn't. If you create the product anew each time you might want to add a timestamp or some other unique ID, and you might want to clear it down again afterwards.